# Connected components of conformal image of boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, connectedness, plane-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a biholomorphism (a holomorphic map with holomorphic inverse), and suppose $G$ is a bounded open subset of the plane. Let $C$ be a compact connected subset of the boundary $\partial G$ , and consider the set:

$I =  \{y \in \partial \mathbb{D} : \exists (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset G, d(x_n, C ) \rightarrow 0, y = \lim_{n} f(x_n) \}$

Is $I$ necessarily of finite connectivity? That is, does $I$ necessarily have at most finitely many connected components?

It may be worth noting the image will most certainly NOT be connected. For example, take $G$ to be a slit disk, and $C$ a small compact connected interval below the tip of the slit. Then the image of $C$ under the map $f$ will correspond to two connected components of the boundary of the unit disk.

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is not true. If you take $G$ as the first quadrant with all line segments from $0$ to $e^{i/n}$ removed ($n \in \Bbb N$) then $C = \{ 0 \}$ should correspond to countable many points on $\partial \Bbb D$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes, indeed it should, this is basically a flower with infinitely many petals. If you want to post this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention (my mistake) was that $C$ should not be a point component. Nevertheless I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample: Take $G$ as the first quadrant with all segments from $0$ to $e^{i/n}$ for all positive integers $n$ removed, and $C = \{ 0 \}$. Then $I$ consists of countably many points on $\partial \Bbb D$ and is not of finite connectivity.

*Addendum:* Re your comment

> ... that $C$ should not be a point component

With $C$ as the union of the segment from $0$ to $1/2$ and all segments from $0$ to $e^{i/n}/2$ we still have that $I$ is not of finite connectivity.