# Connected components of image of non-degenerate boundary component

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, curves, plane-geometry, conformal-geometry

This is a follow up to my previous question, asked and answered here: [Connected components of conformal image of boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745748/connected-components-of-conformal-image-of-boundary/4745766#4745766)

I omitted this by accident from the last question, so I have created this follow up post. It is the same question as in the link, but I would like to know if the answer is still negative if one assumes $C$ cannot be a single point.

Comment: What about taking $G$ as in your previous question, and $C$ as the origin plus a part of each segment, e.g. from $0$ to $\frac 12 e^{i/n}$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes, that works! Clearly I wasn't thinking very well today.

Comment: I have added it as an “addendum” to the other answer.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot!